# Change position for search bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a search bar in a header of a table, but it's very down, and when keyboard is appearing, the search is not visible. How can I do a scroll in table when search bar is too down and no visible? Else I don't want to change the position of it.

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

and if I change the frame for search bar I get this:

[image]

```
-(BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {


    if (self.searchBar.frame.origin.y>270) {
        self.cowTableView.frame=CGRectMake(self.cowTableView.frame.origin.x,self.cowTableView.frame.origin.y-300,self.cowTableView.frame.size.width, self.cowTableView.frame.size.height);}


    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)searchBarShouldEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    self.cowTableView.frame=CGRectMake(self.cowTableView.frame.origin.x,self.cowTableView.frame.origin.y+300,self.cowTableView.frame.size.width, self.cowTableView.frame.size.height);
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you must adopt the [UISearchBarDelegate Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UISearchBarDelegate) on your `UISearchBar`, within that protocol you will need two delegate methods to determine when the user has began and ended using the `UISearchBar` in your table view's header.

```
-(BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    //Called when user clicks search bar
    return YES;
}
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    return YES;
}
```

You do need to determine the position of the `UISearchBar` on screen because I assume you will always want it to be at `(0,0)` on the screen. To do this call `rectForRowAtIndexPath:` to obtain the current y-position of your cell within the table view. Once you have the y-position you have to determine the current offset of the table view and use that value to set the position of `UISearchBar`

```
//Determine the position of the cell relative to the screen origin
CGRect cellRect = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cellRect = CGRectOffset(cellRect, -self.tableView.contentOffset.x, -self.tableView.contentOffset.y);
```

Now `cellRect` will contain the correct values for you to call `setContentOffset:animated:` on your table view.

```
[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(cellRect.origin.x, self.tableView.contentOffset.y - cellRect.origin.y ) animated:YES];
```

Now your `UISearchBar` will be located at the top of the screen.

Comment: your ideea works for change the frame , but why the size for search bar is changed. I didnt modify size, only the origin.

Comment: @AdinaMarin Perhaps you are moving it too high and it seems like the search bar size changed? If you didn't modify the size of the header or search bar it shouldn't change.

Comment: Why are you changing the `frame` of the table view? You only need to change the offset.